# Uninitialized constant error when connecting to a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, typhoeus

I have a service that is running on `'http://localhost:4567/order_summary'` so when I go to that address it shows me the JSON representation of it which is what I want.

Now in another Rail application I created a Controller as simple as this to start working on calling that service and working with its JSON:

```
class PharmacyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    result = Typhoeus::Request::get('http://localhost:4567/order_summary')
    @code = result.code
  end
end
```

but when I go to `http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/` address I get the error of

```
NameError in PharmacyController#index

uninitialized constant PharmacyController::Typhoeus
```

What is it that I should initilaize it based on that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I can see is that you might not have Typhoeus in your Gemfile or you didn't require it `require 'typhoeus'`

Does that help?